# How to import personal modules to airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I tried to Add the S3ToRedShiftTransfer2 using the standard way

```
from  .modules.S3ToRedShiftTransfer2 import  S3ToRedShiftTransferC
```

I got :

```
×Broken DAG: [/c/AIRFLOW/dags/my_my_my_my_airflow.py] attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Also tried to do under my Ubuntu subsystem where airflow webserver is running:

```
export $AIRFLOW_HOME=/c/AIRFLOW
export $PYTHONPATH = ${PYTHONPATH}:${AIRFLOW_HOME}
```

I Always got the same Error.
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `from  dags.modules.S3ToRedShiftTransfer2 import  S3ToRedShiftTransferC` work?

Comment: No, even I entred all the file path